# How to make sidebar background stretch all the way down page

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I'm trying to code up a site from scratch using my own theme, and so far I've been successful except for the sidebar. The sidebar is white, and I'm trying to make it extend all the way down to the bottom of the site, even if the post area is longer than it is.

I've tried stuff like `position: absolute; bottom: 0; top: 0; height: 100%; min-height` but nothing works! Right now, the code I have is:

```
#secondary {
       width: 19%;
       padding: 250px 30px 30px 30px;
       top: 0;
       margin-left: 13%;
       background-color: white;
       position: absolute;
}
```

Just for reference, here's the test site with a post that is longer than the sidebar. I want the white background to extend all the way down till the end of the post --

http://escapism.adriftonvulcan.com/index.php/2015/06/09/arc-review-the-summer-of-chasing-mermaids-by-sarah-ockler/

Any help will be much appreciated!

Comment: What is the parent element? body? or inside a wrapper? try setting your html and body to height: 100% and set parent element to body with body being position: relative;

Comment: I had a bunch of other parent elements that weren't necessary, but I removed them and did what you suggested and it worked! Thank you so much!!!

Answer (score 1):

This is one of the solutions.

Include this jQuery code in footer:

```
<script>
  var height=$('#primary').height(); // Calculate primary wrapper height
  $('#secondary').height(height); // Set the height it to sidebar
</script>
```

**Output:**
[image: Full height sidebar]

Comment: I like this solution because you can have a simple sidebar CSS for the entire site and then just add a few lines of JavaScript on pages that need a sidebar with a certain background color specified inline. Very nice. JavaScript to the rescue yet again! :)

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work

```
#sidebar {
    background-color: white;
    position:absolute;
    left:0;
    top:92px;
    bottom: 0;
    width:13%;
    }
```

This code styles a sidebar div that runs to the bottom of the page and when I run it it does that. I know you allude to it in your post but setting

```
bottom : 0;
```

should work

Comment: Thanks for your reply! I actually had a bunch of parent elements over the sidebar that weren't necessary and when I removed them and added `position:relative;` to the body, that worked. :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Hello in the example which you given is fixed sidebar layout here is the css for the side bar.

```
#secondary{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    width:200px;
    height:100%;
    display:table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: You won't be able to scroll to the bottom of the sidebar if it's taller then the screen height by using position: fixed;

Answer (score 0):

You can try this Javascript. It worked for me.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
resizeDiv();
});

window.onresize = function(event) {
resizeDiv();
}

function resizeDiv() {
vpw = $(window).width();
vph = $(window).height();
$(‘#secondary’).css({‘height': vph + ‘px’});
}
```

I got it off [here](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/setting-a-div-height-to-the-window-viewport-size/). Worked one of my projects.